# python error 'dict' object has no attribute: 'add'

Tags: python, dictionary, addition

I wrote this code to perform as a simple search engine in a list of strings like the example below:

```
mii(['hello world','hello','hello cat','hellolot of cats']) == {'hello': {0, 1, 2}, 'cat': {2}, 'of': {3}, 'world': {0}, 'cats': {3}, 'hellolot': {3}}
```

but I constantly get the error

```
'dict' object has no attribute 'add'
```

how can I fix it?

```
def mii(strlist):
    word={}
    index={}
    for str in strlist:
        for str2 in str.split():
            if str2 in word==False:
                word.add(str2)
                i={}
                for (n,m) in list(enumerate(strlist)):
                    k=m.split()
                    if str2 in k:
                        i.add(n)
                index.add(i)
    return { x:y for (x,y) in zip(word,index)}
```

Comment: Did you expect `word` and `index` to be sets, perhaps?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

In Python, when you initialize an object as `word = {}` you're creating a `dict` object and not a `set` object (which I assume is what you wanted). In order to create a set, use:

```
word = set()
```

You might have been confused by Python's Set Comprehension, e.g.:

```
myset = {e for e in [1, 2, 3, 1]}
```

which results in a `set` containing elements 1, 2 and 3. Similarly Dict Comprehension:

```
mydict = {k: v for k, v in [(1, 2)]}
```

results in a dictionary with key-value pair `1: 2`.

Comment: dict comprehension is `{k:v for ...}`

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes, thanks for the heads up. I'm more used to `dict((k, v) ...)` hence the mistake :)

Answer (score 7):

```
x = [1, 2, 3] # is a literal that creates a list (mutable array).  
x = []  # creates an empty list.

x = (1, 2, 3) # is a literal that creates a tuple (constant list).  
x = ()  # creates an empty tuple.

x = {1, 2, 3} # is a literal that creates a set.  
x = {}  # confusingly creates an empty dictionary (hash array), NOT a set, because dictionaries were there first in python.
```

Use

```
x = set() # to create an empty set.
```

Also note that

```
x = {"first": 1, "unordered": 2, "hash": 3} # is a literal that creates a dictionary, just to mix things up.
```

Answer (score 1):

I see lots of issues in your function -

1. In Python `{}` is an empty dictionary, not a set , to create a set, you should use the builtin function `set()` .
2. The if condition - `if str2 in word==False:` , would never amount to True because of operator chaining, it would be converted to - `if str2 in word and word==False` , example showing this behavior -

   ```
   >>> 'a' in 'abcd'==False
   False
   >>> 'a' in 'abcd'==True
   False
   ```
3. In line - `for (n,m) in list(enumerate(strlist))` - You do not need to convert the return of `enumerate()` function to list, you can just iterate over its return value (which is an iterator directly)
4. Sets do not have any sense of order, when you do - `zip(word,index)` - there is no guarantee that the elements are zipped in the correct order you want (since they do not have any sense of order at all).
5. Do not use `str` as a variable name.

Given this, you are better off directly creating the dictionary from the start , rather than sets.

Code -

```
def mii(strlist):
    word={}
    for i, s in enumerate(strlist):
        for s2 in s.split():
            word.setdefault(s2,set()).add(i)
    return word
```

Demo -

```
>>> def mii(strlist):
...     word={}
...     for i, s in enumerate(strlist):
...         for s2 in s.split():
...             word.setdefault(s2,set()).add(i)
...     return word
...
>>> mii(['hello world','hello','hello cat','hellolot of cats'])
{'cats': {3}, 'world': {0}, 'cat': {2}, 'hello': {0, 1, 2}, 'hellolot': {3}, 'of': {3}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def mii(strlist):
    word_list = {}
    for index, str in enumerate(strlist):
        for word in str.split():
            if word not in word_list.keys():
                word_list[word] = [index]
            else:
                word_list[word].append(index)
    return word_list

print mii(['hello world','hello','hello cat','hellolot of cats'])
```

Output:

```
{'of': [3], 'cat': [2], 'cats': [3], 'hellolot': [3], 'world': [0], 'hello': [0, 1, 2]}
```

I think this is what you wanted.